# Javascript loop through an array and return the object(s) that end a streak of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
let segment = [
  {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", jam_factor: 5.12002},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", jam_factor: 3.13285},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", jam_factor: 2.84637},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", jam_factor: 3.57281},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", jam_factor: 5.2812},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", jam_factor: 8.39212},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", jam_factor: 7.38261},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", jam_factor: 6.28182},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", jam_factor: 4.15984}
];
```

I want to create a function that loops through this array and filters/returns entries that end a (minimum) streak of three lower values (<10), **and** at the same time start a (minimum) streak of three higher values (10). This should also work the other way around (filter entries that end a streak of three higher values (10) **and** at the same time start a streak of three lower values.)

In the example above, the desired output should be an array with the following two objects:

```
{timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", jam_factor: 10},
{timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", jam_factor: 8.39212}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: What you have tried till now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is not yet sorted by timestamp, then first do that:

```
segment.sort((a,b) => a.timestamp.localeCompare(b.timestamp));
```

Then, if I understand correctly you want to filter entries that end a streak of three lower values, **and** at the same time start a streak of three higher (10) values.

After your edit to your question, the code now also detects the inverse (start of a streak of three lower values after three higher ones):

```js
function filter(segment) {
  let result = [];
  let count = 0;
  let prevIsTen, j;
  for (let i = 0; i < segment.length; i++) {
    let isTen = segment[i].jam_factor === 10;
    if (isTen === prevIsTen) {
      if (++count == 3 && j) result.push(segment[j]);
    } else {
      j = count < 3 ? 0 : i;
      count = 1;
    }
    prevIsTen = isTen;
  }
  return result;
}

let segment = [
  {timestamp: "2020-09-23T14:01:59.425Z", jam_factor: 5.12002},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T20:02:20.656Z", jam_factor: 3.13285},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T21:02:28.307Z", jam_factor: 2.84637},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T22:04:09.648Z", jam_factor: 3.57281},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T04:00:54.857Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T05:01:47.202Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T06:02:27.773Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T07:01:43.621Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T08:01:07.918Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T09:02:48.843Z", jam_factor: 5.2812},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T10:02:44.509Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T11:01:47.002Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T12:02:46.718Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-25T13:00:32.164Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T05:02:44.037Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-28T14:01:57.837Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T11:01:34.661Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T17:02:20.367Z", jam_factor: 10},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", jam_factor: 8.39212},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-29T19:00:39.818Z", jam_factor: 7.38261},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T03:01:49.720Z", jam_factor: 6.28182},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T05:01:35.621Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T06:00:27.023Z", jam_factor: 5.98176},
  {timestamp: "2020-09-30T07:03:00.132Z", jam_factor: 4.15984}
];

console.log(filter(segment));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's correct! However this should also work the other way around (e.g. filter entries that end a streak of three higher (10) values and at the same time start a streak of three lower values.)

Comment: OK, I didn't read that requirement in your original question. I have adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Last question: what is the best way to add an extra variable to the output indicating whether a streak of three lower values has ended ("start") or started ("end"), like in the example below. 

`[
  {"timestamp": "2020-09-24T23:02:10.257Z", "jam_factor": 10, "start_end": "start"}, {"timestamp": "2020-09-29T18:02:23.282Z", "jam_factor": 8.39212, "start_end": "end"}
]`

Comment: You can add that property with for instance: `segment[j].start_end = "start"`. You'll need to pinpoint when to put "start" and when "end" as value, but I'll leave that for you to determine. If you cannot make it work, then I suggest your provide all information in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant? We would still like to see your own effort

```js
const arr = [
{ tz:1, jamfactor:10 },
{ tz:2, jamfactor:10 },
{ tz:3, jamfactor:7 },
{ tz:4, jamfactor:8 },
{ tz:5, jamfactor:9 },
{ tz:6, jamfactor:10 },
{ tz:7, jamfactor:10 },
{ tz:8, jamfactor:10 },
{ tz:9, jamfactor:8 },
{ tz:10, jamfactor:9 },
{ tz:11, jamfactor:10 },
{ tz:12, jamfactor:7 },
{ tz:13, jamfactor:8 },
{ tz:14, jamfactor:9 },
{ tz:15, jamfactor:10 }
]

let cnt = 0
const jf = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (cnt === 3 && item.jamfactor >= 10) {
    acc.push(item)
    cnt = 0
  } else {
    if (item.jamfactor < 10) cnt++
    else if (item.jamfactor >= 10) cnt = 0
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(jf)
```